# rgtk2: help in html

Tags: r

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
```

Is it possible to have help files in html called from a gwidget?

ghtml gives the following error:

```
> Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ".ghtml",
for signature "guiWidgetsToolkitRGtk2"
```

Apostolos

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no such luck.

The ghtml widget is only supported in gWidgetsWWW2 and gWidgetsQt (both just on r-forge, not CRAN). The RGtk2 toolkit doesn't provide an underlying html widget to leverage. I should have a better error message though.

If you want prettier html help, you might look at the helpr package.